# Is it a bad choice for a language which doesn't conform to common asymptotic complexities

Tags: algorithm

We know that we can access to any character in string by index in `O(1)` time complexity. Suppose I am on coding rounds and using language which access operation to character in string costs `O(n)` in. During the interview can I just say that

> Assume that strings support random-access operation in constant time

though it isn't actually? Is it really important that language you use should conform to all conventions about complexities? Or we can make assumptions?

Comment: What do you mean, "can we make assumptions"? If you know that something is false, how can you "assume" that it's true?

Comment: For instance, access to character in string by index is `O(1)`, that's true, as for array. But in Swift string's access by index is`O(n)` (that is due to Unicode symbols), it's specific feature of language itself. During the algorithms interview can I assume that string's access is `O(1)` since asymptotic complexity of the algorithm should not be bounded to concrete language?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"since asymptotic complexity of the algorithm should not be bounded to concrete language? "*. If you write a computer program, and your program is super slow because of the way it's implemented, you can't claim "but it's an implementation of a supposedly-efficient algorithm, so let's pretend it's efficient".

Comment: If the theoretical algorithm has, say, O(n) complexity, but your implementation has O(n³) complexity, then your implementation is simply not faithful to the original algorithm.

Comment: Here is a paper that describes a simple "implementation of the sieve of Eratosthenes" in a given programming language (the most simple algorithm to find prime numbers) and then explains why this implementation is, in fact, not at all the sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm, even though it looks like it at first glance. https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I think we don't understand each other. 

What I mean is that during the interviews in FAANG-like companies there are plenty of coding rounds where you are given some algorithmic task to solve with discussion about ds&algos. Discussion is not relative to concrete language you are coding, but to common theory about ds&algos. So your language is just a tool for coding, not more. And the fact is a lot of languages support random string's access in `O(1)` but not Swift language. So can I assume during the interview(only!) that my language supports `O(1)` indexing?